# matlab coding -wavelet toolbo-to find the highest frequency content of a signal from its co efficients

Tags: matlab

i want to find the frequency content  of a signal from  its wavelet co efficients ..i have obtained the co- efficients by decomposition of the signal to high and low frequency components up to a certain level ..now i have to find the highest frequency component in it ..i have done it using fft but is there any other method that i can use ..

```
y_256=Th;
    T_fft=fft(y_256);
    T_fft1=T_fft(1:length(y_256)/2+1);
    freq1=0:8000/length(y_256):4000;

    IX = abs(T_fft1)>0.6;
    ix = find(IX);
    bmax= freq1(ix(end));
```

Answer (score 0):

pwelch:

```
[Pxx,f] = pwelch(x,window,noverlap,f,fs)
```

OR (hassle free, use defaults)

```
[Pxx,f] = pwelch(x,[],[],[],fs)
```

documentation:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/pwelch.html